# Does this SDL_gfx code involve a race condition?

Tags: c, graphics, sdl, race-condition, non-deterministic

When I run the following code on my machine, it doesn't behave deterministically. The triangle it should draw only appears sometimes:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_gfxPrimitives.h>

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    int xres = 250;
    int yres = 250;

    SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(xres, yres,
        0, SDL_SWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF | SDL_NOFRAME);

    SDL_FillRect(screen, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 0, 0, 0));
    filledTrigonRGBA(screen, 10, 10, 170, 170, 75, 100, 255, 0, 255, 255);
    //SDL_Delay(1);       // this fixes some race condition?
    SDL_Flip(screen);
    SDL_Delay(1000);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

But if I uncomment the first SDL_Delay() call, the triangle always appears. I have also observed this when using SDL 2.

Is there a race condition in one of the libraries here, or is something wrong with my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things involved, especially if you have compositing window manager. Like if you flip your resulting image but window wasn't visible at that moment. With compositing it is even worse since it implements its own double buffering.

Just repeatedly draw it a loop, like every single example does. If you absolutely have to, you can redraw only on window events (mostly 'exposed' one).

Comment: This makes sense, but there is another mystery. If I change the above code to blit an image to the screen surface (instead of drawing a triangle), it always works. So do these timing issues only occur when using SDL_gfx?

Comment: No it isn't. Probably image loading/blitting takes more time so window gets properly displayed at that point, but you shouldn't rely on it. This isn't the first time I see similar questions; just don't do that, it makes little sense for game-like applications, and without special care your displayed image wouldn't persist anyway (e.g. overshadowed by other window).

Comment: I was mainly interested in knowing why the phenomenon happens. I've accepted your answer.. it is enough, I guess, to know that other threads involved in window rendering do cause time-sensitive effects. I have seen people discuss these complications when using the X Windows libs; didn't realize SDL does not abstract them away.